# Dismissing queued DialogFragments -- They just keep coming back

Tags: c#, android, android-fragments, xamarin

I am learning how to develop an android app in Xamarin, but virtually the same should apply to the Java original. I am trying to implement a multiple-dialog process through which to edit certain features of a database entry. 
I have two of these for the time being -- TimeChangeFragment and DateChangeFragment. I create them in my MainActvity and have interfaces, called OnNewTimePass and OnNewDatePass respectively, through which I send back the user's input and notify the MainActvity that it should dismiss this DialogFragment, show the next and so on.

The code looks as follows:

#### Dialog Fragments:

```
   public class TimeChangeDialog : DialogFragment
    {

        public int _id;
        ViewGroup _container;

        public interface OnNewTimePass
        {
            void onNewTimePass(DateTime date, int id);
            void openDateDialog(int id, Bundle savedInstanceState)
            void closeTimeDialog(ReminderTimeDialog dialog);
        }

        public OnNewTimePass dataPasser
        {
            get; set;
        }

        public static ReminderTimeDialog NewInstance(Bundle bundle)
        {
            ReminderTimeDialog fragment = new ReminderTimeDialog();
            fragment.Arguments = bundle;
            return fragment;
        }

        public override void OnAttach(Activity a)
        {
            base.OnAttach(a);
            dataPasser = (OnNewTimePass)a;
        }


        public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            /*onCreate, inflateView, handle dataetc.*/
            Button buttonNext = view.FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.DialogButtonNext);


            buttonNext.Click += delegate {
                goToNext(view,savedInstanceState);
           //Dismiss();
            };
            return view;


        }


      public override void OnDismiss(IDialogInterface dialog)
        {
            base.OnDismiss(dialog);
            Dismiss();
        }


        public void goToNext(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            /* handle data here */
            dataPasser.onNewTimePass(_workingtime, _id);
            dataPasser.openDateDialog(_id, savedInstanceState);
            dataPasser.closeTimeDialog(this);
        }
    }
}
```

#### Main activity: (implements TimeChangeFragment.OnNewTimePass,

```
DateChangeFragment.OnNewDatePass) ###
    public void closeTimeDialog(dialog){
    FragmentTransaction ft = FragmentManager.BeginTransaction();
    ft.Remove(dialog);
    FragmentManager.addToBackStack('close-time');
    ft.Commit();

    //Also tried i.e. dialog.Dismiss(); here
    }
    public void openDateDialog(int id,Bundle bundle) {
                 FragmentTransaction ft = FragmentManager.BeginTransaction();
                  //Remove fragment
                  Fragment prev = FragmentManager.FindFragmentByTag("dialog");
                  if (prev != null)
                  {
                      ft.Remove(prev);
                  }

                  ft.AddToBackStack("date-dialog");
                // Create and show the dialog.

                TimeChangeFragment dateDialog = DateChangeFragment.NewInstance(taskdata);
                  dateDialog.Arguments = taskdata;
                  dateDialog.SetStyle(DialogFragmentStyle.NoTitle, 0);
                  dateDialog.Show(ft, "date-dialog");

    /*handle data here*/

            }
```

And similarly for the DateChangeDialog, only there I called no openNextDialog().

#### The error:

When I leave the final dialog fragment, in a moment, the first fragment reappears, starting the process all over again.

#### Note:

I have been at this for a couple of days now and read many of the suggestions posted here as far as closing singular DialogFragments and similar issues. I have tried most of them. One said that the Fragments themselves handle their own transactions, so calling Dismiss() inside them is the correct approach (and overriding OnDismiss()). When I do that, however, the second fragment doesn't even appear, even if openDateDialog() is called before Dismiss(); Or, even more bizzarely, its OnAttach gets called, but the dialog itself doesn't appear. 
I havetried leaving all of the fragment management to the Main activity in one case and to the fragments in the other(even letting the second fragment get created from within the body of the first,) but it seems to persist.
One suggestion I have read said that the backstack needs to be popped to the state of no dialogs or that the transactions need to be given priority, not just put on the back stack. I have tried the latter to no avail. As for the former, it is still unclear to me where the transactions should be handled. If within the MainActivity, how do I properly reference the dialog to close. If within the DialogFragment, how do I get the FragmentManager when that itself is part of the activity? Thanks very much in advance for any answers.

Comment: Could you please share a basic demo that can reproduce this problem?

Comment: @Elvis Xia ["Here"](https://mega.nz/#!rZZTwIjT!wRlOvGCc0KR2QKGBcZpbdk-jyyWsV5FZ8S5IAKBo1NY") is a link to only the necessary bits of the reproduced problem. I didn't consider it advisable to upload the whole solutio, so hopefully I haven't missed any files. Thanks for looking into this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> When I leave the final dialog fragment, in a moment, the first fragment reappears, starting the process all over again.

The first date dialog showed up again because you never get it dismissed.

To fix the problem, you can add a reference to the first `datedialog` and dismiss it when you are dismissing the second dialog(`timedialog`):

MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity : Activity, ReminderDateDialog.OnNewDatePass,ReminderTimeDialog.OnNewTimePass//,taskedit_BaseFragment.OnChangeAddDataPass
{
    DateTime _tempDateTime = DateTime.MinValue;

    ReminderDateDialog dateDialog;// use a variable to temporarily store the date dialog
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);

        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);
        var btnChange =FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.ReallySurelyAButton);

        btnChange.Click += delegate
        {
            openDateDialog(3,bundle);
        };
    }

    public void closeTimeDialog(ReminderTimeDialog dialog)
    {
        FragmentTransaction ft = FragmentManager.BeginTransaction();
         ft.Remove(dialog);
         ft.AddToBackStack("close-time");
         dialog.Dismiss();
        dateDialog.Dismiss();// dismiss the date dialog after the time dialog;
    }

    ...

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. However, it doesn't seem to be helping. The Dialog just reopens either way. I have added listeners to the OnAttach thing in the date dialog and it just spontaneously gets called right after I exit the time dialog. I really feel like there is some absolutely basic principle of how these things work but reading up on it online has only added to my confusion.

Comment: It works here, [FragmentReproduceProblem](https://github.com/elvisxia/FragmentReproduceProblem) is the test project I made from your codes. Please have a check.

Comment: Oh, wow, cool. Yes, it works now. Thank you so much for the time you put into this, you've saved me a lot of hair.  Apparently, the issue arises if you dismiss the DateDialog right as soon as clicking next. This way it works like a charm.